# aws KCL(Kinesis Client Library) library is throwing errors when building

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kcl

I am following this link to start amazon KCL, Kinesis Client Library, because I need to use nodeJ. 
I following steps here:
 https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client
But when I run mvn clean install -Dgpg.skip=true, I got error as below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project amazon-kinesis-client: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: 
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - error: error reading /Users/frankhe/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/26.0-jre/guava-26.0-jre.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/Users/frankhe/projects/aws/kinesis/amazon-kinesis-client/amazon-kinesis-client/target/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR]
```

what's wrong there? Is aws kcl is still working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that jar is corrupted. Remove the jar and try again.